# Transactions and validation in Rails4

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions

I have a problem with Rails 4 and validation. Let's consider this model:

```
# has integer attribute 'order'
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent,
  validate :orders_must_be_sequence

  def orders_must_be_sequence
    orders = []
    parent.items.each do |i|
      orders << i.order
    end
    orders.sort!
    errors.add :order, "is not in a decent order" if orders != (0..orders.length - 1).to_a
  end
end
```

There is a parent model `Parent` which `has_many :items`. The idea is, that the items for every parent are ordered; thus for every parent, the **n** associated items have to have the order attributes **0** to **n-1**. This is checked with the `orders_must_be_in_sequence`-validation.

Now for the problem:
In order to reorder the items, the `item` have to be saved. My idea was, to do that in a transaction like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  item1.order = 2
  item2.order = 3
  item3.order = 1
  item1.save
  item2.save
  item3.save
end
```

But then all `save` fails due to the failing validation. Also `validate: false` seems not to be the answer, since I still had to invoke `save` **with** validating at the last time in the transaction.

So I want to do a couple of saves in a transaction and I want that all saves are validated at the commit-time. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could shift the validation logic for being in order into the parent itself, for example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  parent.item1.order = 2
  parent.item2.order = 3
  parent.item3.order = 1
  parent.save

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item

   validate :orders_must_be_sequence

   def orders_must_be_sequence
    orders = []
    parent.items.each do |i|
      orders << i.order
    end
    orders.sort!
    errors.add :order, "is not in a decent order" if orders != (0..orders.length - 1).to_a
   end
end
```

Other than this - I'm curious why you don't just use "sort!" or "order" (to retrieve using ORDER BY SQL), which will guarantee the order, obviating the need to order validation.

Comment: I don't think, that would work, because the parent object is not even touched when reordering the items.